# How do C++ containers work together with the Liskov Substitution Principle?

Tags: c++, liskov-substitution-principle, covariant, covariant-return-types

For return types *Covariance* of the return values are required by the *Liskov Substitiution Principle*.

Lets assume the small type hierarchy for return types:

```
class B {};
class D : public B {};
```

The working classes then could have

```
class Base {
    virtual B& func();
};
class Derived : public Base {
    virtual D& func();
};
```

and this would be compliant to the *LSP* because the return types are *covariant* (the hierarchy of `Base` and `Derived` is "co" to `B` and `D`).

What if *containers* do come into play?

```
class Base {
    virtual vector<B>& func();
};
class Derived : public Base {
    virtual vector<D>& func();
};
```

Is this still LSP compliant? Are `vector<B>` and `vector<D>` "covariant" to `Base` and `Derived`?

Additional question: Does it make a difference for the LSP if I use pointers as container types (allowing for dynamic polymorphism), i.e. `vector<B*>` etc?

Note: I tried not to rely on the real C++ override rules but mainly want to understand LSP. I did nor use the `override` keyword intentionally. First I want to understand LSP then I could try out if C++ supports these rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vector<B>` and `vector<D>` are two completely unrelated types, so it is not LSP compliant.

`vector<B*>` and `vector<D*>` are also two completely unrelated types as far as the C++ type system is concerned.  Since `B` is a base class of `D`, you could just use `vector<B*>` for both, and covariance would not then be an issue.

Comment: Yes, it seems that C++ does not allow it. But `vector<D*>` **behaves** correctly, doesn't it? So from a computer science point of view it would be ok?

Comment: `vector<D>` doesn't allow adding elements of type `B`, so no, it doesn't behave correctly as a replacement for `vector<B>`. An immutable vector of `D` would be close, but then you'd finally hit a fundamental deficiency of C++ - it doesn't support this type of covariance.

Comment: @towi You _could_ `reinterpret_cast` a `vector<D*>` to a `vector<B*>` and it would work (in this case).  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I think it is. I try to map computer science onto C++ practice. BTW: I love it that you write "you *could*", because I won't :-)

Comment: The `reinterpret_cast` is **not safe**, because it allows the insertion of `B*`s that aren't `D*`, which is a problem if you have another reference with type `vector<D*>`. This is why mutable containers aren't covariant.